# Conditional dependence of counters

Tags: counters

Consider two counters `A` and `B` and the initial value of `B` is the same as of `A`.

```
\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}
\setcounter{A}{1}
\setcounter{B}{\theA}
```

Consider the commands `setA` and `setB` to change them.

```
\newcommand{\setA}[1]{\setcounter{A}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setB}[1]{\setcounter{B}{#1}}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}
\setcounter{A}{1}
\setcounter{B}{\theA}

\newcommand{\setA}[1]{\setcounter{A}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setB}[1]{\setcounter{B}{#1}}

\begin{document}
A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip
\setA{3}

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip
\setB{5}

A=\theA

B=\theB
\end{document}
```

[image]

### 1st variant

Suppose we want to change also `B` when we change `A`. So we could define

```
\newcommand{\setA}[1]{\setcounter{A}{#1}\setcounter{B}{\theA}}
```

But in this case if we change `B` after we had changed `A` they will be different.

**1st MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}
\setcounter{A}{1}
\setcounter{B}{\theA}

\newcommand{\setA}[1]{\setcounter{A}{#1}\setcounter{B}{\theA}}
\newcommand{\setB}[1]{\setcounter{B}{#1}}

\begin{document}
A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip
\setA{3}

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip
\setB{5}

A=\theA

B=\theB
\end{document}
```

[image]

If we change `B` first and later if we change `A`, the previous `\theB` will be lost and of course they will be equal.

```
\begin{document}
\setB{5}

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip
\setA{3}

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip

A=\theA

B=\theB
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Desired output

I'd like to make `B` dependent of `A` **if and only if** the command `\setB` was not used *anywhere* in the code.

In other words, the code below would produce

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\setB{5}

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip
\setA{3}% from here I want to keep \theB because it was used

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip

A=\theA

B=\theB
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure I can follow you here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I want to make `B` independently of `A` if and only if its initial value was changed any time via `\setB`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}
\setcounter{A}{1}
\setcounter{B}{\value{A}}


\newif\ifB
\Bfalse


\newcommand{\setA}[1]{\setcounter{A}{#1}\ifB\else\setcounter{B}{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\setB}[1]{\global\Btrue\setcounter{B}{#1}}

\begin{document}


\setB{5}

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip
\setA{3}

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip

A=\theA

B=\theB



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Smart solution.

Comment: It's better avoiding `\theA` for setting the value of a counter: `\value{A}` is the best; in the case of `\setA`, just use `#1`. I also set `\Btrue` globally, because that's the usual behavior for counters.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option: Let the representation of `B` print `\theA` until `\setB` is used.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{A}
\newcounter{B}
\setcounter{A}{1}
\setcounter{B}{\value{A}}
\renewcommand{\theB}{\theA}

\newcommand{\setA}[1]{\setcounter{A}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setB}[1]{\renewcommand{\theB}{\arabic{B}}\setcounter{B}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setB{5}

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip
\setA{3}

A=\theA

B=\theB

\medskip

A=\theA

B=\theB

\end{document}
```

Note that we use `\value{A}` to set `B` rather than `\theB` as the latter might not be numeric.

Comment: Thanks for let me know about `\value{}`. It will be useful to me.

Comment: @Sigur: Yes. Try your example with `\newcounter{A} \renewcommand{\theA}{\alph{A}}` ...

Comment: Ow, yes. This I know. But since I am working with tikz calendar I think that it should be numeric values.